# Stored subprogram of type procedure that should include 5 tables: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I am trying to build a stored subprogram of type procedure that should include 5 tables.
I am getting the errors "14/2 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored" "17/7 PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator". Please could you help with this. Thank you!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE medicamente_queries
(nnume Functionar.Nume%TYPE)
IS 
tel Telefon_functionar.Numar%TYPE; 
nr number(1):=0;
BEGIN
SELECT t.Numar INTO tel
FROM Telefon_functionar t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Functionar f
ON t.CNP= f.CNP
WHERE f.Nume= nname;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Functionarul '||nname||' avand telefonul '||tel||' a emis 
cererile:');
FOR i IN (
SELECT id_vanzari, CodProdus, Stoc  
FROM ProduseVandute p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Functionar f
ON p p.codprodus = f.codprodus
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vanzari vanz
ON p.id_vanzari =vanz.id_vanzari
LEFT OUTER JOIN Furnizor fur
ON vanz.CUI=fur.CUI
WHERE f.Nume = nnume) LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.CodProdus||' pentru functionarul '||i.Stoc||' cu vanzarile 
'||i.ID_Vanzari);
nr:=nr+1;
END LOOP;
IF nr=0
THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nu au fost emise cereri');
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'Nu exista functionari cu numele '||nnume);
WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20102, 'Exista mai multi angajati cu numele '||nnume);
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20103,'Alta eroare!');
END; 

EXECUTE medicamente_queries;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got `p` where you don't need it, here in cursor FOR loop:

```
SELECT id_vanzari, CodProdus, Stoc  
FROM ProduseVandute p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Functionar f
ON p p.codprodus = f.codprodus
   -
   ^
   here
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vanzari vanz
ON p.id_vanzari =vanz.id_vanzari
LEFT OUTER JOIN Furnizor fur
ON vanz.CUI=fur.CUI
WHERE f.Nume = nnume
```

---

Apart from that, always specify table alias in `select` column list. The way you have it now, query will raise `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` because it is unclear which table `id_vanzari` belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

You probably solved your problem already, but I made some changes. In the end, you didn't declare the input parameter.In my table codprodus is cod_produs.You may do the changes accordingly.

```
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE medicamente_queries
(nnume Functionar.Nume%TYPE)
IS 
tel Telefon_functionar.Numar%TYPE; 
nr number(1):=0;
BEGIN
SELECT t.Numar INTO tel
FROM Telefon_functionar t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Functionar f
ON t.CNP= f.CNP
WHERE f.Nume = nnume;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Functionarul '||nnume||' avand telefonul '||tel||' a emis 
cererile:');
FOR i IN (
SELECT p.id_vanzari, p.Cod_Produs, p.Stoc  
FROM Produse_Vandute p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Functionar f
ON  p.cod_produs = f.cod_produs
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vanzari vanz
ON p.id_vanzari =vanz.id_vanzari
LEFT OUTER JOIN Furnizor fur
ON vanz.CUI=fur.CUI
WHERE f.Nume = nnume)LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.Cod_Produs||' pentru functionarul '||i.Stoc||' cu vanzarile 
'||i.ID_Vanzari);
nr:=nr+1;
END LOOP;
IF nr=0
THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nu au fost emise cereri');
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'Nu exista functionari cu numele '||nnume);
WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20102, 'Exista mai multi angajati cu numele '||nnume);
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20103,'Alta eroare!');
END; 
/
EXECUTE medicamente_queries('ANA')
```

Comment: Thank you, @Florin. At the end, after doing some research, I had to re-write the procedure entirely, for only 3 tables, as my diagram supports it

Comment: @oana You welcome ,if I see other posts from you, I will try to help you. Bafta!

Comment: Thank you, @Florin. I managed to pass my exam with your help, guys!! Thank you thousands time!